# Have hours and minutes show as a decimal

Tags: excel, vba

I have times in the "hmm" format and I would like them to be displayed as decimals.

Example:

```
500 PM = 17
500 AM = 5
828 AM = 8.47
828 PM = 20.47
945 AM = 9.75
1000 AM = 10
1000 PM = 22
```

I've tried using left and right but times and dates are longs, so it didn't work and I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Try `=HOUR(A2)+MINUTE(A2)/60`.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by 24. Can easily be accomplished with VBA if necessary.

```
=A1*24
```

[image]